# React + Laravel - Response.data showing HTML

Tags: reactjs, laravel

The response.data is showing HTML code instead of JSON data

Tried changing from string to array for the state among others

Api.php

```
`Route::get('/adminUsers', 'AdminController@users');`
```

Admin Controller:

```
public function users(){
    $users = User::all();
    //$xx = response()-> json([
//'users' => $users,
//]);
   //dd($xx);
    return response()->json([
   'users' => $users,
]);
}
```

React.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route}     from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'
class Admin extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)    
    this.state = {
         users:  []
         // console.log(users)
    }
}
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('/adminUsers')
        .then(response =>{
            // this.setState({users: response.data})
            console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log(error)
        })
}

render() {
    const{users} = this.state  
...................
```

Simply get the JSON data in an array form

Comment: Can you add the output you are getting now?

Comment: Its is giving the HTML of the page to be rendered.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Vaidam Theme designed by YoCreativ</title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="gUxcnTlHhelpGhO5ooOmukPGphhPEbxjT0djWh37">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="http://eexpedise.org/css/bootstrap.css" type='text/css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://eexpedise.org/css/smoothbox.css" type='text/css' media="all" />

Comment: share the html data received. Are you sending back a csrf_token ?

Comment: Then can you test on your users function to put `dd($request->ajax());` at the start and see what's the output?

Comment: Iam new to react.
Using JWT for Login purpose.
No CSR Token being passed in this particular page and I do not know how to pass it.

Comment: I believe you are being redirected for some reason

Comment: check react documentation  
headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  },

Comment: AdminController is showing below data which is correct.
 "id" => 1
            "name" => "Amit Khare"
            "email" => "amit.khare588@gmail.com"
            "email_verified_at" => null
            "password" => "$2y$10$n7SrEYH5c8EyymiHAfuRnezznuooeTKqKhBaJpomi24z/UwH5F1X6"
            "role" => "$2y$10$m3tMIMri.83pNkTxEoIWieJ52Z9Cn6WKciqLYM5JSSarnMxaSNj56"
            "remember_token" => null
            "created_at" => "2019-08-30 14:42:58"
            "updated_at" => "2019-08-30 14:42:58"

Comment: @Emeka Mbah How to check Headers?
Any link or any specific file?

Comment: Please confirm your request enters `public function users(){` method

Comment: It does. Here's the code too.
public function users(){
        $users = User::all();
    //    $xx = response()-> json([
 //   'users' => $users,
 //  ]);
    //     dd($xx);
        return response()->json([
   'users' => $users,
  ]);
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198765/discussion-between-emeka-mbah-and-amit-khare).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your routes.You might have to prefix your react routes with `api`

like so:

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('/api/adminUsers')
        .then(response =>{
            // this.setState({users: response.data})
            console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```